# I try to fetch data from firestore in my flutter app but , I got this error

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
D/ConnectivityManager(21222): requestNetwork and the calling app is: com.example.ecommerce
I/DynamiteModule(21222): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(21222): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler(21222): callback not found for CALLBACK_AVAILABLE messag

Comment: Seeing same issue...wasn't having any issues a week ago when I was last in my codebase. Updated firebase_core to "^1.10.0", cloud_firestore to "^3.1.0", and also tried adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> and <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> to AndroidManifest.xml but Firebase is still not connecting.  Tested on both emulator with updated Google Play and Pixel 4 running latest Android.

Comment: Error I was seeing ended up being a red herring to actual issue.  Ahmed, maybe if you describe what the overall issue you are having, you may be able to ignore these log messages.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help,  I was asking for my friend,  and he solved it succefully,  so thanks so much bro,  for your help ❤

Comment: I will ask him what he has done to solve it,  then I will inform you bro.

Comment: So his mistake is that he tried to fetch  data with a wrong collection name,  he used  capital "C" instead of small one,  so I think it was a trivial mistake,  but he solved it 